# How to take the smallest date of a group?

Tags: sql, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataset which looks like that:

| id |  status  | open_date | name |
| 8  |  active  | 2019-3-2  | blab |
| 8  |  active  | 2019-3-8  | blub |
| 8  | inactive | 2019-3-9  | hans |
| 8  |  active  | 2019-3-10 | ana  |
| 9  |  active  | 2019-3-4  | mars |

I want to achieve the following:

| id |  status  | open_date | name | status_change_date |
| 8  |  active  | 2019-3-2  | blab | 2019-3-2
| 8  |  active  | 2019-3-8  | blub | 2019-3-2
| 8  | inactive | 2019-3-9  | Hans | 2019-3-9
| 8  |  active  | 2019-3-10 | ana  | 2019-3-10
| 9  |  active  | 2019-3-4  | mars | 2019-3-4

for each id I like to calculate when the status has last changed

I already tried with groupBy, but the problem is I only want to group by the rows with Active and Inactive which are next to each other. If there is an INACTIVE between ACTIVE I like to make a new group for the new ACTIVE.

Someone has an idea to solve that?

Comment: You can add an additional SELECT MIN statement called status_change_date and link the ids.

Comment: the problem is if I use select min for the 4th entry, it would return 2019-3-2. But it should be 2019-3-10 because there is a INACTIVE between

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a pure SQL solution that uses window functions. This works by generating a partition that contains consecutive records that have the same id and status.

```
SELECT
    id,
    status,
    open_date,
    name,
    MIN(open_date) OVER(PARTITION BY id, rn1 - rn2 ORDER BY open_date) status_change_date
FROM (
    SELECT 
        t.*, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY open_date) rn1,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id, status ORDER BY open_date) rn2
    FROM mytable t
) x
ORDER BY id, open_date
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gbEKdc7CJGX44pSHqngs72/0)**:

```
| id  | status   | open_date  | name | status_change_date |
| --- | -------- | ---------- | ---- | ------------------ |
| 8   | active   | 2019-03-02 | blab | 2019-03-02         |
| 8   | active   | 2019-03-08 | blub | 2019-03-02         |
| 8   | inactive | 2019-03-09 | hans | 2019-03-09         |
| 8   | active   | 2019-03-10 | ana  | 2019-03-10         |
| 9   | active   | 2019-03-04 | mars | 2019-03-04         |
```

Comment: very nice solution! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
var movies = [
    {title: 'The Godfather', rating: 9.2, release: '24 March 1972'},
    {title: 'The Godfather: Part II', rating: 9.0, release: '20 December 1972'},
    {title: 'The Shawshank Redemption', rating: 9.3, release: '14 October 1994'},
];

movies.sort(function(a, b) {
    var dateA = new Date(a.release), dateB = new Date(b.release);
    return dateA - dateB;
});
```

This sortby works because js lets you compare arithmetic on date objects, which are automatically converted to numeric representations first.

---

In SQL use MIN function:

ORDER
Id
OrderDate
OrderNumber
CustomerId
TotalAmount

SELECT MIN(OrderDate)
  FROM [Order]
 WHERE YEAR(OrderDate) = 2013

Answer (score 0):

Thats the answer on How to take the smallest date of a group?

```
let minDate = new Date('0001-01-01T00:00:00Z');

dataset.forEach(x => if( x.date > this.minDate) { this.minDate = x.date } ) 

console.log(this.minDate);
```